# sqlite query could not give correct results

Tags: android, sqlite

I have two `tables` one to store `members` and other to store `expense`, when I save any `expense` then there is an option to select the `members` who were present in that `expense`, when I want see the details of any `expense` then in custom `ListView` I would see the name of `member` and amount,but I get the name of member in both `textViews` of custom `ListView`and do not be able to get amount from `expense` Table. I have done like this.

`Adapter class`

```
public class ViewExpenseAdapter extends CursorAdapter {


protected Activity activity = null;
public ViewExpenseAdapter(Activity activty, Cursor cursor) {
    super(activty, cursor, false);
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity = activty;
}

@Override
public void bindView(View row, Context context, Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ViewExpenseHolder holder = (ViewExpenseHolder) row.getTag();
    holder.populateFrom(cursor);
}


@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor cursor, ViewGroup root) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    LayoutInflater inflater = activity.getLayoutInflater();

    View row = inflater.inflate(R.layout.view_expense_row, root, false);
    ViewExpenseHolder holder = new ViewExpenseHolder(activity, row);
    row.setTag(holder);
    return (row);
}

}
```

`Holder class`

```
public class ViewExpenseHolder {

/**
 * 
 */
protected Activity activity = null;
protected TextView memberName, totalAmount;

public ViewExpenseHolder(Activity activity, View row) {
    // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    this.activity = activity;

    memberName =  (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.member_name);
    totalAmount = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.amount_per_member);
}

public void populateFrom(Cursor cursor) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub      

    memberName.setText(cursor.getString(1));
    totalAmount.setText(cursor.getString(3));
}
}
```

the `query` to get the data is

```
public Cursor getPresentMembers(String EXPENSE_ID) {
    //String args [] = {EXPENSE_ID};
    Log.v(DataConstants.MMs_TAG, "All present members returned");

    String query = "SELECT " + " members._id, " + MemberColumns.NAME + ", " 
                    + " expense._id, expense.amount, "
                    + " member_expense._id, member_expense.bridge_id" +" FROM " 
                    + MemberTable.TABLE_MEMBER + ", "
                    + ExpenseTable.TABLE_EXPENSE + ", " 
                    + MemberExpenseTable.TABLE_MEMBER_EXPENSE 
                    + " WHERE " 
                    + " member_expense.exp_id = expense._id "
                    + " AND expense._id = " + EXPENSE_ID
                    + " AND members._id = member_expense._id";

    return db.rawQuery(query, null);
}
```

`ViewExpenseDetail` Activity is

```
public class ViewExpenseDetail extends Activity {

protected Cursor presentMember = null;
protected MMSDataSource source = null;

protected ViewExpenseAdapter viewExpenseAdapter = null;
protected ListView membersList = null;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.view_expense);

    membersList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.present_members);

    source = new MMSDataSource(ViewExpenseDetail.this);
    source.openMMSDatabase();

    String EXPENSE_ID = getIntent().getStringExtra(MemberExpenseColumns.EXPENCE_ID);


    presentMember = source.getPresentMembers(EXPENSE_ID);

    viewExpenseAdapter = new ViewExpenseAdapter(ViewExpenseDetail.this, presentMember);
    membersList.setAdapter(viewExpenseAdapter);
}

public void onBackBtn(View view) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    finish();
}

}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, the same cursor is used for `getMemebrName` and `getExpenseAmount`:

```
public void populateFrom(Cursor cursor) {
    memberName.setText(MemberDataManager.getMemebrName(cursor));
    totalAmount.setText(ExpenseDataManager.getExpenseAmount(cursor));
}
```

Both get methods rely on the same column index 1:

```
public static String getMemebrName(Cursor cursor) {
    return cursor.getString(1);
}

public static String getExpenseAmount(Cursor cursor) {
    return cursor.getString(1);
}
```

So they return both the same value that is populated in the list view row layout. According to your cursor I'd rather expect column index 3 ...

```
public static String getExpenseAmount(Cursor cursor) {
    return cursor.getString(3);
}
```

Comment: Ok dear I have tried this, but now when I select a member then the amount is always `1`, and if I select more than one member the first member is repeated each time instead.

Comment: Have you verified (using ADB shell and `sqlite` command), that your query returns expected values? Using joins you might quickly end up in a situation where column values are repeated.